# os.walk iteration not walking in Python

Tags: python

I'm using os.walk() to check a directory for redundant files and list them out.  The pseudo-code looks something like this:

```
def checkPath(path):
    do the for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path) thing here...

pathList = ["path1", "path2"]

for each in pathList:
    checkPath(each)
```

So this works fine the first run through, I get everything as expected, but on the next os.walk on the second path it just skips right on through...there's nothing in dirname, dirnames, filenames.  I did some print statements to check things out, and it's entering the function, but not doing anything for the os.walk() part.

before making the os.walk() part a function to see if it would fix the problem, it was in a for loop inline with the main body.  When I tried (just for fun) cleaning up the dirname, dirnames, filenames variables with del, on the second path when the cleanup came it said that the variable dirname did not exist...

So it looks like, whether within a function or not, the successive iterations of os.walk() arent populating...

ideas?

Thanks!

---

To add some working code as an example, something like this.  It doesn't really matter what it's doing, just trying to get the os.walk to walk mult paths:

```
import os

def checkPath(path):
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            print filename

pathList = ["c:\temp\folder1", "c:\temp\folder2"]

for path in pathList:
    checkPath(path)

print "done"
```

It could be done this way (was trying to see if calling os.walk in a different way, like one of the other commenters suggested, might help), or it can be done inline, whatever works obviously...

thanks again all,

Comment: What is the path it's skipping?

Comment: Show some *working code* that demonstrates your problem...

Comment: the paths are simple, local folders of test data (spreadsheets, docs, etc.).  pathList = ["c:\temp\folder1", "c:\temp\folder2"].  Each of these folders has subfolders with a few files in them.  In this case it's processing through the first folder, goes to the second folder, but os.walk seems to yield nothing in the dirname, dirnames, filenames variables...

Comment: @user1229108 This is prosa, not **code**.

Comment: @user1229108 What exactly do you mean with "nothing"? Empty string, empty list, `None`, ...?

Comment: by nothing, I mean that when it enters the checkPath() function the second time, it should be walking the directory specified and printing each of the filenames in the example above...instead it nothing prints out...the variables are most likely empty because it seems that os.walk() isn't actually walking the folder.

Comment: if the path given to os.walk does not exist, the for loop just terminates without assigning anything to the variables or printing anything out. How about adding a print statement above the for loop to make sure the directory exists: `print 'checking', path, os.path.isdir(path)`.

Comment: Try ending your folder paths with trailing slashes? Example "C:\\temp\\folder1\\" or "C:/temp/folder1/"

Answer (score 7):

Your code works for me, if I use actual paths on my system which refer to non-empty directories.

I suspect you might have an issue with the line...

```
pathList = ["c:\temp\folder1", "c:\temp\folder2"]
```

...since both `\t` and `\f` are valid escape sequences.

Try...

```
pathList = ["c:\\temp\\folder1", "c:\\temp\\folder2"]
```

...and if that's not the problem, then it would help to cite the actual code you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but tried that as well.  It also doesn't work with raw string, r"c:\temp\folder1"

Comment: @user1229108 The only other thing I can think of is that the second path doesn't actually contain any files.

Comment: as for posting code, this is all I'm using...seriously...just these few lines to test walking two or more directories and I'm not getting anything after the first.

Comment: @Ant I assume that was a joke - do not reinstall python

Answer (score 4):

`os.walk` returns a generator :-) http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

There are a few workarounds:

use a list

1. `ll = list(os.walk())`
2. call `os.walk()` each time
3. use `itertools.chain`

The code you posted should not have this problem (you call os.walk each time), but it makes me really think about generator exhaustion. So post your code as you wrote it [0]

[0] for example, do you have some sort of predefined argument in your function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example

```
import os

def checkPath(list_path):
    for path in list_path:
        for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
            print len(files)

checkPath(["F:/","F:/"])
```

[See doc:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either
>   top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at
>   directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath,
>   dirnames, filenames).

EDIT:

as mentioned in your answers, `os.walk()` returns a generator. A generator can be iterated through once only. It is not a structure storing values, but generates the values on the fly, as it is called. That's why your second loop on `os.walk()`, you have no more results. You may ask `os.walk()` each time you need it, or store `os.walk()` to an iterable.

Comment: reformatted this way and gave it a run.  I added a print statement after "for path in list_path:" to print the name of the path.  For the first path it prints integers indicating the number of files in each folder and subfolder.  This is what I've been seeing.  But when it prints that it's moving on to the next path, the path prints, and then the script ends.  There isn't even a 0 informing that it walked but had no returns...

Comment: this works for me too, tested it on 2 folders, added "print path" below the first for loop to make sure.